Anyone want to defend Philosophy SE, against upbraidments at r/AskPhilosophy?
Our Frank Hubeny referred to https://www.reddit.com/r/AskPhilosophy, but they are upbraiding Philosophy S.E. Anyone keen to responding to these upbraidments?

I don't want to focus on the formality level, but philosophy stackexchange is particularly bad. Stackexchange is used by software engineers, computer scientists, and sometimes math people. The Philosophy forum is mostly filled with people that generate nonsense.


Philosophy stack exchange is shit, even though stack exchange is perfectly useful for maths. Anything about formality is a speculation which comes after as to the differences between maths and philosophy, but there are other reasons why it’s shit too (it isn’t well positioned to be full of good philosophy!).


Besides, on just empirical grounds, philosophy stack exchange is generally of fairly low quality (at best).

I am just the messenger, be nice to me! Please move this to Meta. I don't got enough member points to post there.

A literal reading of that comment is "software engineers, computer scientists, and sometimes math people" are "people that generate nonsense", which is just poisoning the well (and it would also be kinda ironic to say that on a platform built by SEs and CSs, who also built basically every single other website there is). A more generous interpretation is that those people aren't philosophers, but that doesn't necessarily mean the arguments here are bad or wrong (but I certainly won't say you should trust something just because someone said it here, but also not in published philosophy FWIW).

The top-voted comment gets close to making a good point, but then falls off the wagon completely by suggesting that merely knowing who someone is makes it appropriate to cite them. The actual good point they should've made is that this site doesn't have peer review from verified philosophers or other mechanisms that could be said to reliably lead to high-quality arguments (which Reddit doesn't have either). Then again, philosophy tends to be quite subjective, and you should evaluate arguments by their own merits, not by who said them. Merely being published doesn't mean that much in philosophy

@NotThatGuy Just want to say that I don't like the term "verified philosophers." If you do philosophy, that makes you a philosopher, regardless of what institutions you might or might not be attached to. There is no objective criterion to distinguish "good" philosophy from "bad" philosophy, and "being attached to an institution" is not such a criterion. Plenty of bad philosophy comes out of people attached to institutions.

@causative Makes sense.

It's a fair cop. half the questions on the site should rightly be closed immediately and half the answers to the good questions show no knowledge of the subject matter. People who would never for a moment think that someone who had no education in computer science should be answering computer science questions, yet think that they, with no knowledge of philosophy should be answering philosophy questions.

@DavidGudeman Ironically, there are lots of people with no (formal) education in computer science (or programming, rather) who provide many useful answers on Stack Overflow (the same could probably be said about the Computer Science site), and who have well-paying jobs as programmers. But there are certainly people who post incorrect or nonsensical answers because they have no idea what they're talking about - it's usually quite easy to point out specific problems with what they've said. There are also people who don't know much, but still manage to post good answers based on what they know.

@DikranMarsupial, I wasn't suggesting that people have to have a formal education to answer question. Most of my knowledge of philosophy was gained informally. However that's different from someone who tries  to answer a technical question based non-technical understanding of the words used.

The Reddit thread is concerned with a person who referenced a Philosophy StackExchange post in a PowerPoint presentation and was criticised for it. There isn't much context. If the reference was just a matter of saying: here is where I got the idea from, then I don't see a problem. If it was intended as a citation of an authoritative source then that is a problem. StackExchange is not an authoritative source, but then neither is Reddit, nor Wikipedia for that matter.
As to the critical comments themselves, it is fair to say that the material on StackExchange is a very mixed bag. There are good and bad questions and there are good and bad answers. The voting system is supposed to help identify the good ones, but it is not used much on the Philosophy site. I don't follow the askphilosophy subreddit but a cursory look suggests that the answers there are no better than the ones here. They are typically very short, unsourced, naive, and sometimes incorrect.
It is a general problem with a philosophical site that everybody feels qualified to contribute, even if they have little or no knowledge of the subject matter. Both Philosophy StackExchange and the askphilosophy subreddit say that they aim to provide contributions that are serious and well-researched and that they are not discussion sites. Despite this, both contain material that is trying to push a personal point of view.
I doubt there is a simple solution to this.

I think the accusation of nonsense generation is a fair reflection of philosophy generally.

Then why are you on the group?

@DavidGudeman I didn't say it was all nonsense!!!!

You are one funny dude @MarcoOcram!
